# Tabs width 100%

Tags: html, css

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SAcQE/) is my code. I want  list to fill the full width from #page. I tried with `width:100%;display: inline-block`  , but no result.
How can i do it (if it is possible)?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `width:100%; display: inline-block;`, with semicolons instead of commas?

Comment: Ah, I see an actual fiddle. Good! Can you strip that css to a bare minimum to reproduce the problem? It's kinda hard to grasp what's going on with all the gradients and other irrelevant markup.

Comment: I define width: 980px for the wrapper and i try to do ul list with width:100% from #page.

Comment: I deleted all gradients.

Comment: do you want to increase the width of the TabContents or the TabHeader?

Comment: I want to increase the width of all tabs and when i add a tab i want to resize all tabs.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li {
float: left;
width: 20%; /* 100% / (tab's amount) */}
```

I've created [a small example](http://jsfiddle.net/khtNW/), take a look and compare to your code, maybe it will help you to find a solution.

Comment: this code resize the wrapper but i want to resize the buttons over it. :(

Answer (score 0):

Add position:relative; in #page
And then add width:100%; in #tabs it will adjust to #page with 100% width.
also remove the margin-left and margin-right.

Comment: Hi, i think i wasn't very clear /sorry for this/ - I want to resize the buttons.